# Show that a polar equation describes a circle

Tags: calculus, circles, polar-coordinates

I want to prove that this polar equation:

$$r^2 + 2r(\cos(\theta) - 3\sin(\theta)) = 4$$

describes a circle.

I tried converting the equation into a cartesian equation and got

$$r^2 + 2x - 6y = 4$$

and this is basically where i got stuck. Where do I go from here, or am I proving this in the correct way at all?

Comment: you dont see that $r^2 + 2x-6y = 4$ can be turned into $x^2 + y^2 +2x-6y = 4$ which represents a circle with center $(-1, 3)$ and radius $\sqrt{14}?$

Comment: Carry on from where you are using $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$

Comment: @abel: I'm guessing OP *didn't* see that, which was the reason for the question; no need to be dismissive of those with less experience than you.

Comment: Changing my answer to a comment: A circle is described in polar form by $r=a$ where $a$ is a constant. Therefore,
$$\frac{dr}{d\theta}=0$$ So if the equation you are given describes a circle, then $\frac{dr}{d\theta}=0$. All you have to do is prove this. Implicit differentiation will be needed, though.

Comment: @abel: I have to agree with John Hughes. Not only dismissive, but really kinda crappy because you just gave the final answer (and I don't know if it's correct because you didn't show any work) without showing how to get there. If that appeared in a question, it would probably be massively downvoted.

Comment: @abel I did not see that... It's what I was looking for, basically. But I did not want the solution... I wanted to work it out on my own

Comment: @HDE226868 thanks! That helped! That moment when you haven't done implicit differentiation in like 2 years!

Comment: @MahmudAssamaray I'm glad. I'll undelete my answer, then; I wasn't sure if it would help.

Comment: thanks @BadAtMaths, I can't believe I did not see that... I've been staring at this for so long

Comment: @MahmudAssamaray: your original idea was fine and you are almost there. If you sub in $x^2 + y^2$ for $r^2$ you will get an expression which, upon completing the square, will give you the equation of a circle.

Comment: It appears that the first equation in the Q should read $ r^22+2r \cos \theta -6r\sin\theta=4$  which is not what i see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A circle is described in polar form by
$r^2-2rx_0\cos(\theta - y_0)+x_0^2=a^2$
where $a$ is a constant and $x_0$ and $y_0$ represent the coordinates of the center of the circle. Therefore,
$$\frac{dr}{d\theta}=2rx_0\sin(\theta-y_0)$$
So if the equation you are given describes a circle, then $\frac{dr}{d\theta}=2rx_0\sin(\theta-y_0)$. All you have to do is prove this. Implicit differentiation will be needed, though.

Comment: The equation $r=\sin(\theta)$ describes a circle, but we have $\frac{dr}{d\theta}=\cos(\theta)\not\equiv0$.

Comment: Just a quick other -side- questions. How do you type the formulas like that? i.e. the power is a superscript, theta is the actual letter, and fractions are not diagonal

Comment: [Here's the site's tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), and [here](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) is a handy guide for beginners.

Comment: thanks! @columbus8myhw. didn't know the site had a tutorial!

Comment: Wouldn't $\frac{dr}{d\theta}=0$ only hold for circles centred about the origin?

Comment: @BadAtMaths yes,you are right .this answer is not correct.

Comment: @columbus8myhw I fixed it for the proper general scenario. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @BadAtMaths Fixed.

Comment: @chenbai Fixed.

Comment: @MahmudAssamaray I corrected my answer. Note that you can unaccept answers if you want to, so if you feel that my answer is still lacking after this, feel free to unaccept.

Comment: @HDE226868 it's even better now!